# Renumber all records when one is updated

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010. I have a datasheet form called **Projects** with two fields, [Project Name] and [Priority]. I would like to be able to update the priority number for one of the records and have all other priority numbers update automatically. For example, Project Red is priority 1. Project Orange is Priority 2 and Project Blue is Priority 3. If I update Blue to number 1, I would like Red to update to 2 and Orange to update to 3. Is this possible?

[Projects Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbvac.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That is possible.

Use the *AfterUpdate* event of the textbox with Priority:

```
Private Sub Priority_AfterUpdate()

    Dim rst             As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngId           As Long
    Dim lngPriorityNew  As Long
    Dim lngPriorityFix  As Long

    ' Save record.
    Me.Dirty = False

    ' Prepare form.
    DoCmd.Hourglass True
    Me.Repaint
    Me.Painting = False

    ' Current Id and priority.
    lngId = Me!Id.Value
    lngPriorityFix = Nz(Me!Priority.Value, 0)
    If lngPriorityFix <= 0 Then
        lngPriorityFix = 1
        Me!Priority.Value = lngPriorityFix
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

    ' Rebuild priority list.
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.MoveFirst
    While rst.EOF = False
        If rst!Id.Value <> lngId Then
            lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityNew + 1
            If lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityFix Then
                ' Move this record to next lower priority.
                lngPriorityNew = lngPriorityNew + 1
            End If
            If Nz(rst!Priority.Value, 0) = lngPriorityNew Then
                ' Priority hasn't changed for this record.
            Else
                ' Assign new priority.
                rst.Edit
                    rst!Priority.Value = lngPriorityNew
                rst.Update
            End If
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend

    ' Reorder form and relocate record.
    Me.Requery
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    rst.FindFirst "Id = " & lngId & ""
    Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

    ' Present form.
    Me.Painting = True
    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    Set rst = Nothing

End Sub
```